# How to compare date formats or check if cell is formatted to specific date format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a way to check if a cell is already formatted to a specific date format. If TRUE do something, if FALSE do something else.

Something like:

```
var myDateFormat = "dd"/"mm"/"yyyy" "hh":"mm":"ss"

if (sheet.getRange("A1") === myDateFormat)  {
console.log("TRUE");
}else{
console.log("FALSE");
}
```

The above does not work. What can be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most robust way is to [use the built-in](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumberformat) `getNumberFormat()` or `getNumberFormats()` functions

Let's say I have the following 2 cells, with dates formatted differently:

[image]

I can now write something like this and launch `main()`:

```js
const getDateFormats = range =>
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(range)
    .getNumberFormats()
    .flat();

const main = () => {
  const formatsInRange = getDateFormats('a1:a2')
  console.log(formatsInRange);
  formatsInRange.forEach((format, i) =>
    /^dd\/MM\/yyyy$/.test(format)
      ? console.log(`Value ${i + 1} is OK`)
      : console.log(`Value ${i + 1} is not OK`)
  )
};
```

This script produces the following output:

[image]

The formats that are returned by this function are [referenced here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats). And you can always `console.log()` the needed format first so that you can use it as a regular expression later.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hey Dmitry thank you. I'm learning how to code so arrow functions still get me very confused. How would one rewrite this without arrow functions? Just so I understand the logic behind this. Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting this error `Exception: Argument cannot be null: a1Notation Details`. My dummy file in case you want to have a look: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just spend 15 minutes learning the arrow functions, you will thank me later. Your error is liked to the fact that the getDateFormats function needs to accept a range.

Comment: I am probably dumber than average I already spent more than 1 hour trying and still even though I think I understand I still not sure when I look at someone else's code. But it's ok you are right I will try harder :)

Comment: Oh ok I was executing `getDateFormats` instead of `main`. Thanks!

Comment: So this `/^dd\/MM\/yyyy$/` is what is called a regex form of Javascript expression? If so is there a way of using regular way of expressing date format like `"dd"/"mm"/"yyyy"` or someking of translator tool that will allow translation between the 2 forms of expressing a date format?

Comment: Regular expressions are the best for this purpose, you want to learn the basics of those as well.

Comment: I tried `new RegExp('dd"/"mm"/"yyyy')` but returns as false the 1st date.

Comment: Can you share your new code? I'm on my phone atm, can't try things out :(

Comment: Btw you can also try the === equality operator instead of a regex in this case, it should work

Comment: Sure I was trying this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPEcJ.png

Comment: So in order to use `===` I need to use `ìf ()` or `switch` or something like a condition?

Comment: Try replacing that regex line with 'dd"/"mm"/"yyyy' === format

Comment: No you can keep the ternary operator

Comment: Like this?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/p64Ld.png  It says `SyntaxError: Identifier 'getDateFormats' has already been declared` what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not test(format), just format. You are not calling a function

Comment: Like this ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibynz.png After execution it shows this https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeYFu.png

Comment: Do you happen to have two `getDateFormats()` functions?

Comment: It kind of runs perfectly on my end: https://imgur.com/a/p332jY1

Comment: ahh yes I did have 2! Now it works perfectly! https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2gKP.png

Comment: In the debug console the `var formatsInRange` shows 3 date formats: `'dddd", "d" "mmmm" "yyyy', 'dd"/"mm"/"yyyy'`. Shouldn't it show just 2? The `A1` and `A2` cells? Just so i can understand what the code does. Thank you!

Comment: I was trying to compare multiple date formats like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/esJSq.png. Then change to this `getDateFormats('A1:A')`. The console shows this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEDnT.png. Maybe I need to change something in the code? Use a `for` loop or something? But maybe it's already a different question? I can place a new question I'd be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: Yes, ease do, you kind of lost me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript regex to validate the format of the date string.

```
var pattern = /^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))-([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])-\d\d\d\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]$/g;

if (pattern.test(dateString){
    console.log("TRUE");
}
else{
    console.log("FALSE");
}
```